# Is there a good source listing all newspaper articles/ads in the opening scene of Fantastic Beasts movie?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

The movie *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* starts off with screen wipes (?) of wizarding newspapers, showing articles and ads (I saw screenshots of mentions of Grindewald).

Is there a good source listing all the content being shown on the screen in those newspapers?

Comment: Be aware that the extra text in the images [was not written by J.K. Rowling](http://www.thisisinsider.com/fantastic-beasts-newspapers-2016-11). 
*"We were given maybe half a dozen main headlines to feature," MinaLima co-founder Miraphora Mina told INSIDER. "Everything else that’s on the rest of the paper, we have to create."*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Right now it seems like Mashable is the best source; they acquired some [high-res images of the newspapers](http://mashable.com/2016/12/02/fantastic-beasts-opening-harry-potter-easter-eggs/#bm4_cKGuNSqo). I've tried to pull out as much information as I can, but I regret that I can't make out everything, or any of the actual text of the articles. Here's what I did come up with (click to embiggen images):

- *The New York Ghost* 1 December, 1926

  [image]

  **The ads:**

  - > Sunset Final Edition Last Minute Updates

    This appears to be an ad for the Evening edition of the *Ghost*
  - > Win a rust repellent cauldron
  - > Weather

    Can't make out the forecast
  - > Harbor the magic of the Scottish highlands with Hagpipes

    *[Sigh]*
  - There's a short table of contents
  - > The Chef: This week work your sauce-ery

    Contrary to what I initially believed, this appears to be an advert for a cooking section in the *Ghost*.
  - > Games: Spot the Snargaluff. Rune Riddles. Pygmy Puff [Pelmanism](https://www.pagat.com/misc/pelmanism.html)
  - Along the bottom, we have an ad for a department store:

    > Ebbingdales: Wonders for Wizards
    >
    > Magic on every floor! In New York City, "You know where we are"

  The major headline is:

  > **Grindelwald attacks intensify, risking war with No-Majs**
  >   I.C.W. convened for emergency talks

  Followed by an image of a fire in some building, with the caption:

  > Violent attacks in Europe. Hundreds of casualties reported.

  And then the smaller headlines:

  - > Macusa...is the USA ready?
  - > Love at first bite: the Unlikely tale of a vampire
  - > Black Magic: How to get the most out of your everyday robes
  - > Quidditch Quizzical: How well do you know the National League
  - > The medical modes of the rich and famous
  - > [Stinksap](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Stinksap) extract sourced in best-selling toothpaste

    Ew...
  - > No-Maj ingredients and their place in modern potion-making
  - > Electricity epidemic: Understanding the No-Maj phenomenon
  - > Acclaimed poetess denies hoodwink allegations
  - > Healers demand negotiation over working hours
  - > Bogus seer defies sceptics *[sic]* to win jackpot
  - > Yellowstone disturbances "hold no magical connection" says [Picquery](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Seraphina_Picquery)
  - > Splincher finger chaos at Charleston chicken factory
  - > Fire halts play at annual gobstones convention
  - > Leading sneakoscope manufacturer boasts record sales

  And some public service announcements:

  - Most visibly, "The Macusa Index of Magical Exposure Threat - No. 58,177", I have no idea how to read it, though, so I couldn't tell you if the threat was high or low
  - > Do not forget to Obliviate! The future of our wizarding community is in your wands
  - > Magical Congress of the United States of America Wand Permit Department:
    >
    > Don't be a [Dorcus](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Dorcus_Twelvetrees)!
    >
    > Wand permit renewal is mandatory for all American wizards
    >
    > Please observe all official deadlines and ensure that your paperwork is directed to the Wand Permit Office under supervision of a trusted owl.
    >
    > Failure to comply with federal wand law is a punishable offence, in accordance with the [judicial rulings of Rappaport in the year Seventeen Hundred and Ninety](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/rappaports-law-en). Leniency will not be granted to any witch or wizard who does not pay heed to clear legal guidelines; any breach or disregard of MACUSA's ruling will result in strict disciplinary action. For full details of the relevant bill, please contact your local MACUSA representative.
- *The Daily Prophet* of 29 November, 1926. Bringing news to the Wizarding World since 1743

  [image]

  The ads:

  - > Obscurus Books. Latest catalogue now available! Send a self-stamped owl to get your copy *today*!
  - > New coloumn: Ask D. Shaman
  - Again, the weather I can't make out
  - A Late-Night Final of something I can't make out

  The main headline is:

  > Hogwarts school increases security

  And there are a couple of sub-headlines related to that:

  - > Headmaster calls for emergency meeting with worried parents
  - > Students to be sent home earlier

  And then some more general headlines:

  - > Grindelwald threat: is [Flamboyant Fawley](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hector_Fawley) doing enough?

    Spoilers: no, no he is not.
  - > Ministry of Magic responds to growing public fear
  - > Gringotts on lockdown: protective enchantments cast
  - > Four-headed bird involved in recent Diagon Alley burglary

    Side note, but the [article in the alleged Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Four-Headed_Bird) for this creature is kind of hilarious
  - > The Greek Street Trial: Is Muggle-baiting ever acceptable?
  - > Potioneer [Fleamont Potter's hair potion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/103472/31051) woos American wizards
  - > Interview: Griselda Marchbanks disappointed with poor Charms test results
  - > Exclusive: Mysterious ginger witch under investigation

    The Ginger Witch is [a long-running joke](http://www.businessinsider.com/ginger-witch-harry-potter-fantastic-beasts-2016-11) of MinaLima's, the design firm who works on the *Potter* films; they've slipped references to her into *Prophet* issues seen in most every film.
  - > "Enraptured!" says Dumbledore as Transfiguration Today's new columnist
  - > New Chocolate Frog packaging launched. Who will feature on your collectible card?
  - > Wizard sued in stolen potions scandal
  - > Unusually dry weather causes knotgrass shortage
  - > Magical Law Enforcement Patrol: Now recruiting
  - > Hogsmede to host first ever magical waterplants festival
  - > Ex Minister [Lorcan McLaird](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Lorcan_McLaird) to be honoured by Ravenclaw students
  - > Untransfiguration classes to become compulsory at Hogwarts

  There's also a line of features in the issue along the bottom, featuring:

  - > Spells
  - > Hocus Pocus
  - > Good News
  - > Bad News
  - > Politics
  - > Arts and Farts
  - > Blahblahblah
- An unknown German paper

  [image]

  Main headline translates to:

  > Where is Grindelwald?
  >
  > Dark Wizard still free

  And some other headlines:

  - > Portkey pretzel accidentally eaten - wizard family stranded
  - > German Minister for Magic is convened to the crisis
  - Something about a cursed snowball at a Christmas market; Google translate is struggling with that one
- An unknown French paper

  [image]

  Main headline is:

  > Looking for Grindelwald
  >
  > Dark Wizard fleeing

  And other headlines:

  - > Beauxbaton at the top of the European Quidditch League
  - > Cache of fake wands discovered by magical police
  - > Wizards on the verge of casting secret protection spells

The [MinaLina store](http://store.minalima.com/fantastic-beasts/) has two additional newspaper prints that aren't discussed in the Mashable article (these cannot be embiggened as much; the website has a magnifying feature which I used to extract text):

- Another edition of *The New York Ghost* from December 6, 1926

  [image]

  Many of the ads are the same as the earlier *Ghost* issue, but some new ones:

  - > Sunrise Early Edition. First Minute Updates
  - > CounsOWL ?Questions?

    Appears to be an advice service for owl owners
  - > Lunar Low-Down Moon cycles this week
  - Get a subscription to *The New York Ghost*; 12 months for 5 Dragots

  Main headline is:

  > **Is anyone safe?**
  >
  > Grindelwald spreads fear worldwide

  And smaller headlines:

  - > No-Majs in grave danger warns Picquery
  - > Grindelwald's stratagem? World domination?
  - > Is No-Maj literature worth reading?
  - > The 984th Spell-ing Wasp National Convention arrives in NYC
  - > Halloween sees record-breaking sales of No-Maj brooms. Investment opportunity?
  - > Entertainer convicted after public magical juggling display
  - > Prehistoric manuscript prompts doubt over wandlore dates
  - > Idahoan foxtrot dancer caught drunk behind broom after claiming prize
  - > Confunded No-Majs misunderstand crucial democratic vote
  - > [Scourer](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/seventeenth-century-and-beyond-en) descendants in magical identity crisis
    >
    > Heir reveals blight on family seeking freedom from 'magical shackles'
  - > Family poltergeist goes AWOL following altercation
    >
    > Otherwise clement 'Uncle Edward' jeopardizes Wizard secrecy at family picnic in Central Park, hurling baked goods at passers-by
  - > MACUSA officials demand more witches in the workplace
  - > Venemous Tentacula traps burglar in tenement robbery

  And then some more PSAs:

  - Another MACUSA exposure idnex
  - Another reminder to renew your wand permits
  - > We need Obliviators! MACUSA is recruiting
- An issue of *The Wizarding Voice* dated December 6, 1926

  [image]

  Only one ad:

  > Get vocal in the Voice. Have your say. Send an owl to 75 Lexington Ave.

  Main headline is:

  > **Inexplicable events continue to mystify wizarding community**
  >
  > But are we being sheltered from the truth?

  Smaller headlines as follows:

  - > Is the truth being told about the explosions?
  - > Record numbers attending Romanian warlock convention
  - > A conspiracy of silence?
  - > Gellert Grindelwald: Malevolent and most wanted criminal wizard still at large
  - > Rare spells exercised to conceal the truth
  - > **Exposed: Louisiana swamp monster hair is mystery wand core.**
    >
    > New Orelans wandmaker Violetta Beauvais secret component revealed: [Rougarou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rougarou)

  And another Oblivator recruitment ad

If you have money to burn, you can [purchase prints](http://store.minalima.com/fantastic-beasts/) of the newspaper segments from MinaLima design, the creators of the papers; prints start at £129.

Of course, it's unclear exactly how much input Rowling had into the design of these pages. As [reported by Business Insider](http://www.businessinsider.com/fantastic-beasts-newspapers-2016-11), Rowling did provide several of the headlines and consulted with the designers for some canonical tidbits.

The screenplay itself lists only five headlines, and a couple of descriptions of images:

> MONTAGE:
>
> *We see various magical newspaper headlines from 1926 relating to Grindelwald's attacks all over the world: GRINDELWALD STRIKES AGAIN IN EUROPE, HOGWARTS SCHOOL INCREASES SECURITY, ANTI-WIZARD FEELING ON THE RISE, WHERE IS GRINDELWALD?, IS ANYONE SAFE? He's a serious threat to the magical community and he's vanished. Moving photos detail destroyed buildings, fires, screaming victims. The articles come thick and fast—the worldwide hunt for Grindelwald continues. We push in on a final article displaying the Statue of Liberty.*
>
> <sup>*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay*</sup>

Comment: i love this answer ! if only there were more !